# Why is WebView so much faster than a TextView

Tags: android, performance, webview, textview

I have an activity that's supposed to display a text file. The text file is 165 kB. Originally, after I read in the text file, I would do something like this,

```
textView.setText(fileText);
```

But that took over 10 seconds on my Nexus 4, and I confirmed that this was due to the call to `setText()` and not reading the file. Then, after searching around a bit, I got the idea to put it in a webview, using `WebView.loadData()`. This takes less than a second.

I'm curious as to why a WebView is able to load text so much faster than a TextView. Does anyone know?

Comment: Is it a big text file?

Comment: @hichris123, OP said 165 KB

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Not sure what that means in terms of text, like words.

Comment: It means there are (I'm assuming utf-8) 165K letters. What more is there?

Comment: How did you measure? It may be possible that the WebView does some  layout in the background so that only the beginning of text is really layed out initially.

Comment: as far as i know web view are slow, if i am wrong correct me on this thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember;

The WebView will only render the text that it needs to display at any given time. Meaning that when you first load it will only load 20 - 30 lines of text.  Whereas when you call `textView.setText(fileText);` it causes Android to render all of the text even though it is not displayed.  If you are trying to add a lot of text to a TextView then you should use `textView.append(fileLine);` in a loop which should load quite a bit faster.